# Not able to call function on component can't find variable

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm currently stuck on the following issue.

I have this as my navigationOptions:

```js
static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
    const { state, setParams } = navigation;
    return {
      title: 'Test',
      headerRight: <Button title="Send" onPress={() => {
        uploadImageAsync();

      }}/>
    };
  };
```

I have a function called `uploadImageAsync()`, when I try calling it from here I just get the error `cannot find variable uploadImageAsync`. I've tried with `this.uploadImageAsync()` too but to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In the component. Will post full component for simplicity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with the static `navigationOptions`. You cant access `this` or anything in your component from a static assignment. You will need to move this function to a redux call or a global function that can be used. You could also send it through the navigation props. This can be set through

```
this.props.navigation.navigate(
    'NewPage', 
    {uploadImageAsync: uploadImageAsync}
    /* ^- The assignment in a higher component from the navigate call*/
 )
```

and then accessed through `navigation.state.params.uploadImageAsync()`

Comment: Makes sense now actually. Thanks Daniel